# Vanishing moments and integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification

Is this correct? $\int_\mathbb{R}x^m f(x) dx=0 \iff \int_\mathbb{R}x^m \overline{f(x)}\,dx =0$.

If yes then please tell the conditions under which this holds.

Comment: Here above $m$ is a whole number.

Comment: If $A=B$ then $\overline{A}=\overline{B}$. Do you see how this helps?  (Also, I edited the all-caps title. Please never use all-caps).

Comment: You can also use  Weirstrass approximation theorem .

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ \overline{\int_{\mathbb R} x^m\, f(x)\,dx} = \int_{\mathbb R} \overline{x^m\, f(x)}\, dx = \int_{\mathbb R} x^m \, \overline{f(x)}\, dx $$

Answer (score 0):

We can show that $f(x)==0$ i.e., $f(x)$ must be identically-zero. I think this will work: $f$ can be approximated uniformly in $[0,1]$ by a sequence of polynomials; let $P_n(x): c_0+c_1x+...+x^n$ , so that $Sup_{x \in [0,1]}|P_n(x)-f(x)|dx < \epsilon $. Now sub-in $P_n(x)$, so that $$0=\int f(x)dx=\int c_1xf(x)dx= ...\int  x^nf(x)dx=\int( c_0+c_1x+...+x^n)f(x)dx = \int P_n(x)f(x)=\int (f(x) \pm \epsilon)f(x)dx=\int (f(x)^2 \pm\epsilon f(x))dx=0= \int f(x)^2dx \pm \epsilon \int f(x)dx$$ * (Note for the first equality to zero, we use for $1=x^0 $.)

Now, let $ \epsilon \rightarrow 0$ , and then we have $$ 0 = \int f(x)^2dx $$

from which it follows that we must have $f(x) =0$, e.g., by continuity; if we had $f(x_0) \neq 0$ for some $x_0$ in $[0,1]$, then, by continuity, $f(x)$ would be non-zero in some ball about $x$, forcing the integral to be larger than $0$.

- This carrying of the $ \pm \epsilon $ is a bit unorthodox, but, salvageable, explainable: we can squeeze $\int P_n(x)f(x)dx $ between two integrals, each equal to $ \int f(x)^2 dx$ , and then squeeze  $\int P_n(x)dx $ to be zero from both sides.